# An exercise about matrices and arithmetic

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $n$ an integer, $n>1$.

Suppose there exist two real square matrices $A,B$ of size $n$ such that :

- $A^2+B^2=AB$
- $AB-BA$ is invertible

Prove that $n$ is divisible by $3$.